# Debugging node.js applications

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I installed `node-inspector`

```
sudo npm -g node-inspector
```

to debug i am using `node-debug main.js`

But this brings up the browser window and not the inspector.

Comment: Blank window or the website you are developing? Try changing port for the node app website

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/debug-nodejs-like-a-pro/, start by using --debug-brk option.